# Units for cmd_vel

Tags: navigation, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm implementing my own base_controller to listen on /cmd_vel for motion commands. I'm aware of the REP103 units convention document, but I haven't found anything on what the units in a geometry_msgs/Twist are. I am assuming it's m/s and rad/s?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55977/units-for-cmd_vel/) by [bjoerngiesler](https://answers.ros.org/users/4267/bjoerngiesler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are correct.  Standard units are SI: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8